# Problema ao coletar links de um site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, google

Caros, bom dia! Estou escrevendo um programa em Python para coletar os links de um site. A parte do código a qual coleta os links é:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
time.sleep(1)
```

Testei em alguns sites e rodou de boa. O problema é quando eu uso no Ifood. Ele coleta alguns links e depois retorna vários erros. Sou bem novo em programação, então não sei identificar o que esses erros significam e como posso contornar. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficaria muito grato! Valeu =)

O que o código retorna:

```
https://d1jgln4w9al398.cloudfront.net/imagens/ce/wl/www.ifood.com.br/favicon.ico
https://d1jgln4w9al398.cloudfront.net/site/2.1.238-20181023.22/css/main.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800
https://www.ifood.com.br/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\Python - Projetos\digitar ifood.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 143, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Tudo bem? Dei uma olhada no site Ifood, uma das "href" possui "#content", talvez seu código não entenda esse tipo de informação. É como se fosse uma referencia ao link. StaleElementReferenceException: O seu programa encontrou um elemento que será alterado por Javascript ("#content"). Este usuário tem uma resposta que pode lhe ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43879738/8152489

Comment: Olhando o código-fonte, os links que eu quero estão dentro de elementos que estão em formatos como este:

<a class="restaurant-card-link" href="/delivery/jundiai-sp/china-in-box---jundiai-anhangabau" data-event="SelecionouRestaurante" data-rid="a49ecb3c-bb1a-461d-aab0-5f8bf3ecaa48" data-name="China in Box  Jundiaí" data-price="60" data-brand="" data-category="Chinesa" data-cuisine="Chinesa" data-position="3" data-pos="3" data-evaluation="4,3" data-distance="9.92" data-delivery-time="50" title="Pedir China in Box - Jundiaí | iFood Delivery">

Comment: Você informou que ele coleta alguns links e depois da esse erro. O que ele coleta é o que você quer? O que pode evitar o seu programa dar erro é: Tente colocar uma tomada de decisão para evitar que ele capture as href que contenha JavaScript, palavras iniciadas com "#", por exemplo.

Comment: Então, acho que é o contrário. Ele tá coletando uns links que eu não queria e justo os que eu quero, está dando pau. Será que é por conta do Java? Tem alguma idéia de como posso modificar pra dar certo, ou alguma indicação de onde posso descobrir como fazer?

Comment: Hey! Encontrei um problema semelhante ao seu, aqui está o link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877140/get-all-links-from-driver-find-elements-by-href-not-working       Espero que ajude!

Comment: Wanderson, obrigado pela ajuda. O problema do link realmente é parecido com o meu (aparentemente). Apliquei a solução, mas o erros continuaram. Nessa solução, os elementos são procurados pela tag. Como não rolou, tentei por xpath e por class_name, mas nesses casos a única coisa retornada foi um []. Vou continuar na luta aqui! haha